# Background colors in Rider Debugger Callstack -- How to change them?

Tags: rider

I find it difficult to see which is the currently selected item in the Rider Debugger callstack view.

- How can I change the background colors in the callstack?

I've searched in settings for stuff like "highlight", "selected", "current" with no luck.

[image]

(I'm using the Nord theme)